# Iphone Coreplot

Tags: iphone, charts, draw

I am new to the iPhone development can anybody help me to draw curve chart in iPhone using only three values

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot
{
    NSLog(@"Array1-->%@",Array1);
    return [Array1 count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"Array1-->%@",Array1);
    NSLog(@"marks1-->%@",marks1);

    if(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX)
    { 
        return [Array1 objectAtIndex:index]; 
    }
    else
    {
        if(plot.identifier == @"X Squared Plot")
        {
            return [marks1 objectAtIndex:index]; 
        }
    }
}
```

iploted curve chart using above code but i have many values in each array.. but i want plot using only three values in each array.

Comment: You need to give us a lot more information than you have. Also, please format your code.

Comment: We also need to know what you have tried and what is not working. Looking at your question I have no idea how to help because you have not told us what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot{
    NSLog(@"Array1-->%@",Array1);
    return [Array1 count];
    //return 50;
}
```

with the following one:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot{
    NSLog(@"Array1-->%@",Array1);
    return 3;
}
```

Hope this helps!