# Creating a curved graph

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, graphing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iphone Coreplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053543/iphone-coreplot)

I want to add a graph of a curve to my iPhone app for user input. Can anybody help me with the code?

```
  if(ABS(startPt.x - endPt.x) > ABS(startPt.y - endPt.y)) {
        cPt1 = (CGPoint){(startPt.x + endPt.x) / 2, startPt.y};
        cPt2 = (CGPoint){cPt1.x, endPt.y};
    } else {
        cPt1 = (CGPoint){startPt.x, (startPt.y + endPt.y) / 2};
        cPt2 = (CGPoint){endPt.x, cPt1.y};
```

Comment: Also, please don't double-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053543/iphone-coreplot